# Opencart Помогите убрать/изменить сортирвку в url

Tags: php, opencart

Когда в категории выбираем сортировку товара например по цене, то к url добавляется такое: `?sort=p.price&order=ASC`.
Когда перехожу на страницу товара, то кроме адреса товара в url остается кусок от сортировки `?sort=p.price&order=ASC`. Как убрать это со страницы товара, или где можно изменить?

Файл .htaccess если нужно:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|js|css|svg|woff2)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteRule ^welcome index.php?route=account/register [L]
RewriteRule ^create index.php?route=seller/account-product/create [L]
RewriteRule ^mypage index.php?route=account/transaction [L]
RewriteRule ^confirm index.php?route=seller/account-profile [L]
RewriteRule ^logout index.php?route=account/logout [L]
RewriteRule ^restore index.php?route=account/forgotten [L]
RewriteRule ^edit index.php?route=account/edit [L]
RewriteRule ^security index.php?route=account/password [L]
RewriteRule ^tasks index.php?route=account/order [L]
RewriteRule ^messages index.php?route=account/dialog [L]
RewriteRule ^favorite index.php?route=account/wishlist [L]
RewriteRule ^output index.php?route=seller/account-withdrawal [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: А почему ЧПУ не используете?

Comment: Использую, все равно есть

Comment: @Abmin если используете - приложите код файла .htaccess, возможно он у вас не правильно сформирован.

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил файл .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в **\catalog\controller\product\category.php** закомментируй вот эти строки

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
}

if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
     $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
}
```

Comment: Да, работает. На страницах товара пропало. А как можно изменить на странице категории? Или это сложно?

Comment: @Abmin не сложно, просто муторно, надо GET запрос переделать в POST

Comment: в этом же файле?

Comment: @Abmin в этом, плюс надо еще найти все фалы, в которых есть ссылка, либо отправка запроса на product/categoty